# Include external dll in type library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vba, excel-dna, typelib

I have created a project with some ComVisible methods. To have these available in VBA with Intellisense, I mark the assembly as ComServer in the .dna-file, and generate the .tlb-file using RegAsm in a post-build event. This works great.

I also have another project, that has some ComVisible methods. I would like to have these methods included in that same type library as well. Is this somehow possible?

I thought I could very easily just embed the assembly, which would then do the trick. This is unfortunately not possible. So... any other way I could do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need them joined in a single .tlb file? Perhaps there is alternative way to achieve your goal.

Comment: There is no tooling available to "merge" type libraries.  You can force an `importlib` attribute in the type library to get one type library to import another but that's fickle and error prone both when you generate and use the type library.  The simple solution is the obvious one, just add the source code files to the project.

Comment: can you not just add the other typelib using the Tools - References in VBE? If anything is exposed via a visible com interface it should give you intelli-sense in VBA. If that code is not COM visible IMO you would need to rewrite the entire library and merge it with your current working solution.